# Firebase Custom Domain 404 Error on subdomain

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

How do I fix this 404 error on my custom domain name?

At this subdomain [https://bookmarked.fun/publicprofile/IanHunter](https://bookmarked-d5236.firebaseapp.com/publicprofile/IanHunter) I get a 404 error on my custom domain. 
On firebase's app deploy website, I have no issues https://bookmarked-d5236.firebaseapp.com/publicprofile/IanHunter.

Comment: The first link you shared now works for me.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I just checked the link and it looks like adding in the rewrite config in the firebase.json file fixed the routing 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding in the rewrites to the firebase.json file fixed the routing 404 issue.

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "rewrites": [ 
      {"source":"**", "destination": "/index.html"
  }]
  }
}
```